# When a noun phrase can act as the post-modifier?

Tags: phrases, nouns, modifiers, noun-phrases

According to Oxford Learner's Grammar by John Eastwood [ISBN:0-19-437-597-8], page 187; it is possible for a noun phrase to act as a postmodifier of the head noun.

Example:

- *The weather that day* was awful.

Here, the noun phrase **that day** functions as the postmodifier of the head noun **weather**.

But there is no detailed information on in what cases and what constructions the  noun phrase can function as the postmodifier.

How common is the postmodification of a noun by a noun (or determiner) phrase? Is the determiner necessary? Which determiners occur in such a usage?

Please give only answers including authoritative references.

Comment: I'd suspect that some would hold that whiz-deletion is occurring in 'A car this shade of red is bound to be spotted quickly'. Many would say 'that day' is a determiner phrase, not a noun phrase. Does Eastwood offer any examples other than those including determiners? I'm guessing that 'this colour / shape / size ...' (adjectives are usual with 'this/that high / heavy / long ... / loud / ...') and 'that time / day / night / year ...' (again we use adjectives with 'this/that early, recent, old ...') comprise the vast majority of examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, unfortunately, Eastwood offers the only example, which makes me ask this question here(   do you mean **determiner phrases** can function as post-modifier as well?

Comment: I'm saying that those who subscribe to the determiner phrase analysis wouldn't agree with Eastwood that 'that day' is a noun phrase. See the [Wikipedia] article. If determiners are essential in this sort of structure, it will help enormously in narrowing down the list of possible postmodifiers of the type you're after. The demonstratives (eg _these days_), _some_ days, _most_ days. Often, I think preposition deletion is involved (**on** most days / that day, **in** these days, perhaps **of** that shade of red), and we're probably switching to adverbial modification.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that's what I thought at the beginning, but I am looking for a credible source (I am a non-native). Are you suggesting these hypotheses based on your linguistic background or is it what observation tells us. Thanks for cooperation)

Comment: Eastwood looks useful but limited and, as regards most modern theories, to be treated with care. // I'm usually pretty good (though not infallible) at coming up with examples and especially counterexamples. I don't think there are going to be bare NP modifiers (not counting compounds like the Brothers Grimm, the River Nile). // Requests for resources are off-topic on ELU, though answers should always be referenced. I've adjusted your question slightly.

Comment: If he only gives one example of a phenomenon, and doesn't specify the context, it's obviously unsatisfactory. Start collecting examples and specifying noun and modifiers. A pattern will emerge if there is one.

Comment: Leaving aside apposition, post-head modifiers with the form of NPs are limited to those denoting age, size, and similar properties, as in "a man **my age**", "shoes **this size**", "the results **last year**" OR non-referential distributive indefinites, as in "fifty miles **an hour**", "a salary of $20,000 **a year**", "ten dollars **a head**".  Ref CGEL Huddleston & Pullum 2002

Comment: *“He lives on this side of the river”* and *“He lives this side the river”* Semantically they are identical and grammatically correct. In the latter *“this side”* Is a complement of “lives” and *“the river”* modifies “side”. However, you will note that in *“on this side of the river”* on this side is adverbial to “lives” and *“of the river”* is adjectival to side. They create an adjectival modifier. We see **Det. + N + N**  in “The language department” = the department associated with language. *The weather that day* = **Det. + N + Det. + N** (NP +NP) The weather associated with that day.

Comment: @BillJ, thanks a ton. Now I have a better grasp of the issue.